# React setState key values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate

I have a function in a react app that uses setState

```
...
handleChange: (e, id) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  setState({ id: e.target.value })
}
...
```

The thing is the `id` is just a placeholder for the fields in the state object but everytime the function is triggered it creates a new field `id` and assigns the last updated value in the **form**.
I'm probably doing it wrong so I was wondering if there's a work around or solution to this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since id is a variable that is having the state key value, so you need to use `[]`, what it will happen is, the id will get replaced by it's value.

If you don't use `[]` then id will be treated as a "id" **string**.

Like this:

```
handleChange: (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ [id]: e.target.value })
}
```

Comment: Thanks I had no idea :-)

Comment: glad, it helped you :)